# My code can't read xlsx files at EC2, but do at normal hosts

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, spreadsheet

Good night guys, how are you?

I made an excel spreadsheet reading system in php using the PhpSpreadsheet library and it worked perfectly on my hosting, however when I switched to EC2's client it gives an error when trying to read xlsx tables:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "ZipArchive" not found in /var/www/html/libs/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php:63 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/libs/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php(158): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::fileExists() #1
/var/www/html/libs/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(400): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::assertFile() #2 
/var/www/html/libs/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/BaseReader.php(166): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx->loadSpreadsheetFromFile() #3
```

This sysyem read all kind of files at my host, but at EC2's client only read xls files and don't read xlsx. (it's the same code) Anyone knows how can i fix that?

Comment: note : For some PHP versions , say 7.4 , the ZipArchive is no longer present by default and you need to install and configure it FIRST if you want to use it

Comment: @KenLee i've installed php8.1-zip, but don't appear any config to set up... and error continues

Comment: make sure u restarted httpd after reinstallation

Comment: @KenLee Sorry borrow you again... now, doesn't appear any error, but my EC2 instance go down when i try to read xlsx, but doesn't do it when i try xls... if i use this code at any free hosting it works 100%... you know what can be?

Comment: Ignore, it was an error of ubuntu last version.

Comment: I see, so it is a known bug in ubuntu last version..... Thanks for letting us know.